# Why worldsheet current associated to spacetime supersymmetry is the integral of the vertex opertor?

Tags: string-theory

Sorry, I just haven't enough reputations for adding a comment in that post.

@MISC {389179,
    TITLE = {Polchinski equation 11.2.7},
    AUTHOR = {Nogueira (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/35399/nogueira)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Physics Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389179 (version: 2018-04-19)},
    EPRINT = {https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389179},
    URL = {https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389179}
}

So my question is, why this formula,
$Q_{s}=\oint_C\frac{dz}{2\pi i}\mathcal{V}_s$
is right? Seems most papers just cite it. I don't see any physical reason behind it. Q is the supercharge while V is the vertex operator corresponding to an R or NS sector vacuum. For more detail, one can read Polchinski Vol.2 P50

Comment: OK, I think I find the answer. Just close it please.

Comment: If you have found an answer to a question you already asked it is quite reasonable to write an answer yourself.  This helps the site by not leaving unanswered questions listed and may also be useful to other people - the exact reason Physics SE exists.